# How to combine multiple SQL aggregate queries into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number of queries that I would like to combine into a single query, even though they have a common filtering field, I am not completely sure that what I am trying to achieve is even possible since these are all aggregate queries.

```
declare @salesforceId int
set @salesforceId = 109924

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 1 --general feedback
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 3 --food rating
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 4 --drinks rating
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 5 -- restaurant ambience
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 6 -- service rating
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 7 -- booking service
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 12 -- Recommend Restaurant
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 13 -- Overall Rating
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 525 -- Value for Money
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
COUNT(*) as ReviewCount FROM QuestionResponse qr
                JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
                AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
                AND qr.QuestionId = 526 -- Location
                AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId

SELECT 
count(*) as Total,
    CultureInvariantText AS Tag
    FROM
        SurveyResponse SR 
    INNER JOIN 
        [QuestionResponseFixedOptions] QR ON SR.SurveyResponseId = QR.SurveyResponseId
    INNER JOIN
        QuestionResponseOption QRO ON QR.[ResponseOptionId] = QRO.[ResponseOptionId]
    INNER JOIN
        Question Q ON QRO.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN
        LocalizableText LT ON QRO.ResponseValue = LT.LocalizableTextId  
    where sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId
    group by CultureInvariantText
```

output can be something along the lines of the following:
count is the same across all queries.

```
|GeneralFeedback|FoodRating|....|.....|....|Count|
```

Comment: How your final output should look like? it seems like all queries have same columns you can use UNION All

Comment: Keep the common conditions in the WHERE clause. Use case expressions in the select list to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all accessing the same table, you should do conditional aggregates:

```
AVG(CAST CASE WHEN <condtion> THEN qr.RatingScaleOptionId END as float)
```

You can have as many of those in your `SELECT` clause you like. Just make sure to only keep the common conditions in the `WHERE` clause. The varying conditions then belong into the `WHEN` of the `CASE`.

Read more about this here:
https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can add a surrogate column for telling which aggregate a row represents, format each query to produce identical rows, and use `UNION ALL` to combine them:

```
SELECT 'GeneralFeedback' AS Type, AVG(...) AS Rating, COUNT(*) AS ReviewCount
FROM QuestionResponse ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FoodRating' AS Type, AVG(...) AS Rating, COUNT(*) AS ReviewCount
FROM QuestionResponse ...
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' as Type, 0 as Rating, COUNT(*) as ReviewCount
FROM SurveyResponse ...
```

The row for the `'Total'` is "shoehorned" into the common structure by adding a column with zero rating and calling `Total` a `ReviewCount`. The code that executes this query will need special processing to treat this row separately from other rows coming back from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Please note that I changed the *float* for `decimal`. *You will have better precision, depending on which kind of application you are working for.*
You need to finalize the query according to your ~10 cases.

```
SELECT AVG(  CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 1 THEN CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as decimal) END as GeneralFeedback_Rating
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 1 THEN 1 END)                                      as GeneralFeedback_Count
     , AVG(  CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 3 THEN CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as decimal) END as Food_Rating
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 3 THEN 1 END)                                      as Food_Count
     , AVG(  CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 4 THEN CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as decimal) END as Drinks_Rating
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN qr.QuestionId = 4 THEN 1 END)                                      as Drinks_Count
-- ... ... ...
  FROM QuestionResponse qr
  JOIN SurveyResponse sr
    ON qr.SurveyResponseId    = sr.SurveyResponseId
   AND sr.StatusId           IN (5, 7)
   AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId
   AND qr.QuestionId         IN (1, 3, 4)--1:general feedback, 3:food, 4:drinks, ETC...
```

Answer (score 0):

try group by

```
declare @salesforceId int
set @salesforceId = 109924

SELECT qr.QuestionId, 
       AVG(CAST(qr.RatingScaleOptionId as float)) as Rating, 
       COUNT(*) as ReviewCount 
FROM QuestionResponse qr
JOIN SurveyResponse sr ON qr.SurveyResponseId = sr.SurveyResponseId
 AND sr.StatusId IN (5, 7)
 AND sr.RestaurantNetworkId = @salesforceId 
group by qr.QuestionId
```